# Finding / removing a row from a QStandardItemModel by item data

Tags: c++, qt5, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I have a `QStandardItemModel` with a single column (represents a list). Each item in the list has a unique integer ID stored as the `QStandardItem`'s data (via `QStandardItem::setData` which I guess is into `Qt::UserRole+1` by default).

Given one of these IDs, I'd like to find and remove the corresponding row from the model. Right now I'm doing this:

```
void NetworkManager::removeSessionFromModel (QStandardItemModel *model, int sessionId) {

    foreach (const QStandardItem *item, model->findItems("*", Qt::MatchWildcard)) {
        if (item->data() == sessionId) {
            model->removeRow(item->index().row());
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

It works fine, but every single line of that function makes me cringe. Is there a cleaner way to do any of this?

Comment: [QStandardItemModel::setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setData) uses `Qt::EditRole` by default.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza I'm setting it on the items, [QStandardItem::setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setData), not QStandardItemModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `findItems` wrong, it can already return the item you want just by passing the value you're searching for. If you call it like you're doing right now you're looping through your items at least two times, since `findItems` must iterate through all the items to find those that match your pattern, in your case all items match, then you iterate the returned items again to find the `sessionId`.

```
void NetworkManager::removeSessionFromModel (QStandardItemModel *model, int sessionId) {

    auto items = model->findItems(QString::number(sessionId));
    if (!items.empty()) {
        auto row = items.first()->index().row();
        model->removeRow(row);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [match](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) method since `findItems` uses that internally, so you avoid allocating the `StandardItem` just to get its index. Also `match` returns right after the number of items matching the pattern, in this case the value of `sessionId`, are found so it doesn't always iterate all the items; that's more efficient. Obviously if the value is not found after iterating all the items it returns an empty list.

```
auto start = model->index(0, 0);
auto indexes = model->match(start, Qt::UserRole + 1, QString::number(sessionId), 1, Qt::MatchExactly);
if (!indexes.empty()) {
    auto row = indexes.first().row();
    model->removeRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Hey good idea; `findItems` directly won't actually work in my case since it [calls `match` with `Qt::DisplayRole`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp.html#2619) but the suggestion to use `match` with `Qt::UserRole+1` is the way to go I think. I'll give this a shot today.

Comment: Works like a charm. `foreach (auto index, model->match(model->index(0, 0), Qt::UserRole + 1, sessionId, 1, Qt::MatchExactly)) model->removeRow(index.row());` if you're going for brevity. The indices won't change out from under you during the loop as long as `hits` is set to 1. Also since the match parameter is a `QVariant`, I skipped `QString::number`.

Answer (score 6):

How about traversing the `QStandardItemModel` directly? Something like this:

```
void NetworkManager::removeSessionFromModel (QStandardItemModel *model, int sessionId) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i)
    {
        if (model->item(i)->data() == sessionId)
        {
            model->removeRow(i);
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Not sure how `QStandardItemModel` behaves with random access, maybe your method is more efficient.

**Edit:**

Actually, there is a function to do what you want: [QAbstractItemModel::match](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match)

It returns a `QModelIndexList` with all entries that have matching data in a given role.

```
void NetworkManager::removeSessionFromModel (QStandardItemModel *model, int sessionId)
{
    QModelIndexList list = model->match(model->index(0, 0), Qt::UserRole + 1, sessionId);

    if (!list.empty())
        model->removeRow(list .first().row());
}
```

Setting data to a specific role can be done as follows:

```
model->setData(model->index(row, col), QVariant(13), Qt::UserRole + 1);
```

Comment: OP is probably using `Qt::DisplayRole` as its `sessionId` value, otherwise `findItems` wouldn't work since the implementation calls `match` internally using that role.

Comment: Now that I think about it `QStandardItem::data()` by default returns the value of `Qt::UserRole + 1` and OP is matching on that, and not on `Qt::DisplayRole`, that's probably why OP used `findItems` that way it did.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza I indeed am matching on `Qt::UserRole+1`; I used `findItems("*", ...)` just to get a list of items I could iterate over, and didn't use `findItems` to do the search because it uses `DisplayRole`. But I actually didn't realize `match` existed until I saw your answer.

Comment: @RickPat Sorry man, I might be shuffling answer check marks around. This Q&A is a tough one because I kinda feel like everybody's a winner so far, heh.

Comment: I went with `match`; I chose the other answer since I found it clearer on that point. That said, even though `match` is the most direct code, I find your suggestion with the `int` index to be the clearest to read. So that's another good option.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the row index from your item id.

A more effective way could be to use a QMap with the row index as value and the item id as a key.

In this case, you also need to maintain the map values every time you add/remove a row.

If you don't have 3 millions items in your list, just keep it simple and use your code.
By optimize this code, you probably also add complexity and reduce maintainability, and you get is 0,05 ms instead of 0,06 ms.

In GUI code, I often have code like this : it's simple, everyone get it immediatly and it does the job. It' also fast enough.

Comment: Even though this isn't a direct answer, this is the best advice here. After reading it I was perfectly happy with my code, and changes just became academic at that point.

Comment: It might be better to use a QHash if you have lots of items, I suggest you read [this comparison](https://woboq.com/blog/qmap_qhash_benchmark.html) between QMap and QHash.